# Blazor - submit button needs to be clicked twice even with Task in Radzen form

Tags: blazor, form-submit, asp.net-blazor

I've seen several topics about this issue but can't find a solution. I'm new to Blazor and I'm building a Blazor application but I ran in a problem with submiting the form. I need to click on button twice, even though I've used *async Task InvokeSubmit()* as seen that I should here on one other topic.
It works like a charm if my input loses focus before pressing the submit button (for example clicking somewhere outside input box). I've tried javascript and made it to lose focus when hover a submit button, it works for the first submit, after that event listener from that button simply disappears in dev tools.
Putting bind:event="Oninput" loses focus after each button press so this isn't an option as well since my input string needs to have 5 chars

Here is the form I'm having issues with:

```
    <RadzenTemplateForm TItem=string
                        Data="@NewShortLink"
                        Submit="@InvokeSubmit"
                        class="delivery__agreement-search container bg-white shadow-sm p-3 p-md-5"
                        Style="max-width:820px;">
    
        <div id="wrapContent" class="d-flex flex-column flex-md-row align-items-center align-items-md-end">
            <div id="textboxOrientation">
                <div class="errorMessageOrientation">
                    <div id="passLabel">
                        <RadzenLabel Text=@local["pass"] class="ml-3 mr-auto align-self-end mr-1 text-1 text-uppercase" />
                    </div>
                    <div id="errorMessage">
                        <RadzenRequiredValidator Component="ShipmentId"
                                                 Text=@local["short_link_is_required"] />
                    </div>
                </div>
    
                <RadzenTextBox id="shortLinkInput"
                               class="w-320 mr-md-5 form-control shadow-none text-2-rubik"
                               Style="background-color:#f6f8ff"
                               Name="ShipmentId"
                               MaxLength="20"
                               @bind-Value="@NewShortLink" />
            </div>
    
            <RadzenButton ButtonType="ButtonType.Submit"
                            id="search"
                            class="btn btn-100 btn-primary shadow-sm w-166">@local["search"]</RadzenButton>
        </div>
    
    </RadzenTemplateForm>
  @code {   
        [Parameter]
        public string? NewShortLink { get; set; }
    
        private IJSObjectReference module;
    
        [Parameter]
        public EventCallback<string> Submit { get; set; }
    
        protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
        {
            if (firstRender != null)
            {
                module = await JS.InvokeAsync<IJSObjectReference>("import", "./Pages/Components/UI/Components/CodeInput.razor.js");
            }
        }
    
        private async Task InvokeSubmit()
        {
            await Submit.InvokeAsync(NewShortLink);
        }
    }
```

I've tried putting StateHasChanged(); in the method body after the invokeAsync even though it's not needed since this is not void function, but still nothing happens.
I would be grateful for any help

Comment: This is not standard Blazor: it's Radzen Blazor.  Have you asked Radzen?  Most people here who answer questions are vendor component agnostic, so won't be familiar with the Radzen control set.  PS - I've updated you question Title as this is Radzen specific.

Comment: I have experienced the same issue in .net 7 and blazor after using FocusAsync no library.

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis: ` I've updated you question Title as this is Radzen specific.`: [politely put] no, it is not.

Comment: @enet - I couldn't see past all the Radzen controls!  Hopefully you've found the problem. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

This is caused with the line `TItem=string`
You should instead create a small class which holds the value of what you would like to check.

```
protected class ShortLinkSubmit
{
    public string NewShortLink { get; set; }
}
```

You should then create an instance of the ShortLinkSubmit class, and set the NewShortLink parameter.

Bind `ShortLinkSubmitInstance.NewShortLink` to the RadzenTextBox with the ID of `shortLinkInput`.

Be sure to update the RadzenTemplateForm TITem, Submit argment type, and the Data to the ShortLinkSubmitInstance too.